# Python OOP - Soccer Simulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm new to OOP. I'd like to simulate a soccer match. How do I access Play instance variables in the Player/Offender/Defender classes? If another structure is better, please help.

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move_to(self, x, y):
        self.x = (self.x + x) / 2
        self.y = (self.y + y) / 2

    ## Loop through Play.Players to find nearest. How do I access Play.Players?
    def nearest(self):
        return nearest

class Offender(Player):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y)

    # Move to ball.
    def strategy():
        ball_x = Play.ball_x # how do I access Play.ball_x
        ball_y = Play.ball_y # how do I access Play.ball_y
        self.move_to(ball_x, ball_y)

class Defender(Player):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y)

    # Move to nearest player
    def strategy(self):
        nearest = self.nearest()
        self.move_to(nearest)          

class Play:
    def __init__(self, offense_players, defense_players, ball_x, ball_y):
        self.offense = [Offender(player) for player in offense_players]
        self.defense = [Defender(player) for player in defense_players]
        self.players = self.offense + self.defense
        self.ball_x = ball_x
        self.ball_y = ball_y

    def simulate(self):
        while True:
            for player in self.players:
                player.strategy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Play().simulate()
```

Instead of having `Offender` and `Defender` classes, I have one for each position, i.e. `Striker(Player)`, `Midfielder(Player)`, `Goalie(Player)`, etc. which is why I'd like to store their respective `strategy` in their class and not in the `Play` class.

Comment: The `Player.simulate()` method should pass `self.ball_x` and `self.ball_y` to the `player.strategy()` method as arguments.

Comment: ... and also the coordinates of all other `Players` in the `Play`, so the `nearest()` method can be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just elaborate the idea from the comment of [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau): We just pass the `Play` instance as argument to the relevant methods of `Player`. I also wrote out a very first draft for the `nearest()` method, but you might want to improve its logic. I was just drafting this to demonstrate how you could solve your OOP design problem.

```py
import typing


class Player:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move_to(self, x: float, y: float) -> None:
        self.x = (self.x + x) / 2
        self.y = (self.y + y) / 2

    def nearest(self, play: "Play") -> "Player":
    # This must yet be adapted to handle the edge case of two players 
# having equal distance to the current player. You didn't specify the 
# desired output for that case, hence I just ignored that scenario for now.
        return min([
            p for p in play.players 
            if p.x != self.x or p.y != self.y, # this is to 
# exclude the player itself. 
# This is a buggy logic, because it relies on an assumption that is not  
# validated in the code (the assumption that two different players never 
# have identical coordinates). You might want to introduce a uniqe `id` 
# instance variable to the Player class, to handle this identification in a 
# clean way.
            ],
            key=lambda p: (self.x - p.x)**2 + (self.y - p.y)**2
        ) 


class Offender(Player):
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        super().__init__(x, y)

    # Move to ball.
    def strategy(self, play: "Play") -> None:
        self.move_to(play.ball_x, play.ball_y)


class Defender(Player):
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        super().__init__(x, y)

    # Move to nearest player
    def strategy(self, play: "Play") -> None:
        self.move_to(self.nearest(play=play)          


class Play:
    def __init__(
    self, 
    offense_players: typing.List["Offender"], 
    defense_players: typing.List["Defender"],
    ball_x: float, 
    ball_y: float,
):
        self.offense = offense_players
        self.defense = defense_players
        self.players = self.offense + self.defense
        self.ball_x = ball_x
        self.ball_y = ball_y

    def simulate(self) -> None:
        while True:  # this is still a bad condition, you might want to change this. However you didn't specify your desired logic, so I didn't change it.
            for player in self.players:
                player.strategy(self, play=self)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much this will be helpful for you, as the implementation is in C++

You can checkout my implementation for a similar problem statement https://github.com/rimpo/footballcpp

For understanding the arcade game framework implementation for which the above bot was written, checkout http://richard-shepherd.github.io/coding-world-cup/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

keep track of game state in another (data) class:

```
class GameState:

    def __init__(self, offense_players, defense_players, ball_x, ball_y):
        self.offense = offense_players
        self.defense = defense_players
        self.players = self.offense + self.defense
        self.ball_x = ball_x
        self.ball_y = ball_y
```

You may even wish to use python3.7 [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) (and [some](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) [other](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) features) for this (although it is not at all necessary)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List 


@dataclass 
class GameState:

    offense: List[Offender]
    defense: List[Defender]
    ball_x: float 
    ball_y: float 

    @property 
    def players(self):
        return offense + defense
```

Players then take this state in their strategy and are expected to update their internal state (like position). `nearest` player is implemented by taking the minimum [l2 distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between other players using the key argument to [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) that takes a function of another player, `p` which is written using [`lambda`](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/).

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move_to(self, x, y, other_players):
        self.x = (self.x + x) / 2
        self.y = (self.y + y) / 2

    def nearest(self):
        return nearest

class Offender(Player):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y)

    # Move to ball.
    def strategy(self, game_state):
        ball_x = game_sate.ball_x # how do I access Play.ball_x
        ball_y = game_state.ball_y # how do I access Play.ball_y
        self.move_to(ball_x, ball_y)

class Defender(Player):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y)

    # Move to nearest player
    def strategy(self, game_state):
        # we assume you are moving to offensive players - which 
        # you will not be apart of 
        nearest = min(
            game_state.offense
            key=lambda p: (
                (self.x - p.x) **2 + (self.y - p.y) ** 2
            ) ** (1/2)  # take the l2 norm to find the "closest" player to you
        )
        self.move_to(nearest.x, nearest.y)
```

Then, play the game

```
class Play:

    def __init__(self, game_state):
        self.game_state = game_state

    def simulate(self):
        while True:
            for player in self.game_state.players:
                player.strategy(self.game_state)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Play(GameState(
        [Offender(-1, 0), Offender(-1, -1), ...]
        [Defender(1, 0), Offender(1, -1), ...]
    )).simulate()
```

---

You could then implement some actual players

```
class TiernaDavidson(Defender):

    def strategy(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return better_strategy(*args, **kwargs)
```

You will have to ask [her](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tierna_Davidson) for the implementation of `better_strategy` ;)

Comment: How do you feel about adding a default implementation of `strategy` in the `Player` class?